# Is there a theorem which provides conditions under which a power series satisfies the reciprocal root sum law?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, reference-request, summation

[This  paper](https://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph116A/Sixways.pdf) discusses how to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} $. The first proof on this paper is Euler's original proof:

> $$\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} = 1- \frac{x}{3!}+ \frac{x^2}{5!}- \frac{x^3}{7!}+\dots$$
> The roots of $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ n are the numbers $\pi^2, 4\pi^2, 9\pi^2, 16\pi^2, \dots$ Now Euler knew that adding up the reciprocals of all the roots of a polynomial results in the negative
> of the ratio of the linear coefficient to the constant coefficient. In symbols, if
> $$(x − r_1)(x − r_2)···(x − r_n) = x^{n} + a_{n−1}x^{n−1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{r_k}= \frac{-a_1}{a_0}$$
> Assuming that the same law must hold for a power series expansion, he applied it to $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ ,
> concluding that
> $$\frac{1}{6}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\pi n)^2}$$
> Why is this not considered a valid proof today? The problem is that power series are not polynomials,
> and do not share all the properties of polynomials.

The next page the author wrote this :

> $$\frac{1}{1 − x}=1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots$$
> holds for all $x$ of absolute value less than $1$. Now consider the function $g(x)=2 − 1/(1 − x)$. Clearly, $g$
> has a single root, $1/2$. The power series expansion for $g(x$) is$ 1−x−x^2−x^3−···$, so $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = −1$.
> The sum of the reciprocal roots does not equal the ratio $−a_1/a_0$. While this example shows that the
> reciprocal root sum law cannot be applied blindly to all power series, it does not imply that the law
> never holds. Indeed, the law must hold for the function $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ because we have independent
> proofs of Euler’s result. Notice the differences between $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$  and the $g$ of the counterexample. The
> function $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ has an infinite number of roots, where $g$ has but one. And $\frac{\sin(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$ has a power series that converges
> for all $x$, where the series for $g$ only converges for $−1 <x< 1$. $\color{red}{\text{Is there a theorem which provides
> conditions}}$ $ \color{red}{\text{under which a power series satisfies the reciprocal root sum law? I don’t know.}}$

Now I tried to search for a this theorem and I couldn't find any thing.

Is there is a theorem like this somewhere ? Is there a proof for a  under which a power series satisfies the reciprocal root sum law?

Comment: You need the corresponding hadamard product on the roots (and generally without exponential factors) to be absolutely convergent - this essentially means an entire function of zero genus like $( \sin \sqrt z/)\sqrt z$

Comment: @Conrad How to prove that ?

Comment: Not sure what is the question as the absolute convergence is a sufficient condition though of course it is not necessary per se like with the sine example (where $\sin z/z$ needs Weierstrass factors apriori but one may be able to rearrange factors and get absolute convergence while cancelling them)- if the Hadamard product is absolutely convergent then the result follows from identifying coefficients;

Comment: you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem; the idea is that an entire function can be written as a product on its zeroes (and of course an exponential factor) but those need to be paired with special exponential factors (Weierstrass factors) to ensure convergence; if the function doesn't grow too fast (equivalently the zeroes are fewer and grow faster in modulus) one can dispense with the Weierstrass factors; for example $\sin \pi z/z$ has roots at non zero integers and they are a bit too many, but symmetry allows pairing them, getting squares like above